# jQuery DataTables multi sort with shift key

Tags: jquery, datatables

I enable Jquery datatable like bellow

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
$(table.column(i).header()).unbind('click');
table.on('click', "th:not(.sorting_disabled)", function (e) {
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'th') {
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            table.order(GetSortdir()).draw();
        }
    }
    return false;
});

function GetSortDir() {
    $.map(OldMultiOrderWithDir, function (sort, i) {
        var newObj = [];
        var obj = [];
        obj.push(sort.colIndex);
        obj.push(sort.OrderBy.replace("ending", ''));
        newObj.push(obj);
        return obj;
    });
    return newObj;
}
```

if first time GetSortDir()

> return [[1,'asc']]

then it will working fine.
second times onwards that means it GetSortDir() method

```
return           
 [[1,'asc'],[2,'desc']] or [[1,'asc'],[2,'asc']]
```

then sorting was not working .